# Are these phrases all expressing resultative meaning?

Tags: secondary-predicates, resultative

> Hermione Granger was almost as nervous about flying as Neville was.
>   This was something you couldn't learn by heart out of a book -- not
>   that she hadn't tried. At breakfast on Thursday she bored them all
>   **stupid** with flying tips she'd gotten out of a library book called Quidditch Through the Ages. Neville was hanging on to her every word,
>   desperate for anything that might help him hang on to his broomstick
>   later, but everybody else was very pleased when Hermione's lecture was
>   interrupted by the arrival of the mail.  (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)
>
> From both sides of the valley little streams slipped out of the hill
>   canyons and fell into the bed of the Salinas River. In the winter of
>   wet years the streams ran full-freshet, and they swelled the river
>   until sometimes it raged and boiled, bank full, and then it was a
>   destroyer. The river tore the edges of the farm lands and washed whole
>   acres down; it toppled barns and houses into itself, **to go floating
>   and bobbing away**. It trapped cows and pigs and sheep and drowned
>   them in its muddy brown water and carried them to the sea.   . . . . .
>   . On the wide level acres of the valley the topsoil lay deep and
>   fertile. It required only a rich winter of rain to make it break forth
>   **in grass and flowers**. The spring flowers in a wet year were unbelievable. (John Steinbeck, East of Eden)

I come across adjectives that express result now and then as in the case – bored them all *stupid*.  But I’m not sure that the to-infinitive phrase and prepositional phrase also express the result of the previous action, having the objects as their semantic subjects. Are all the highlighted parts those expressing the resultative meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Resultative* is a nice waffle word which adequately describes the meaning without tying you down to any very rigorous syntactic analysis.

1. I haven’t got far enough in McCawley to know how this particular use of the infinitive clause is analyzed. As a writer I can tell you fairly precisely what Steinbeck is doing. He is adding what amounts to an independent clause (roughly, “and they went floating and bobbing away”); but on the one hand he does not want to cast this in the past tense, where it would interrupt his account of the river's action (*tore* ... *washed* ... *toppled* ... *trapped* ... *drowned* ... *carried*), and on the other hand he does not want imply that the houses' *floating and bobbing* was the river's **purpose**, which might be suggested by such constructions as *so they went floating ...* or *to send them floating ...* He settles on the infinitive adjunct, which provides him a syntactically subordinating form—and not incidentally is about the ‘lightest’ (shortest) construction available.
2. Traditional grammar would treat *in grass and flowers* as an adverbial PP modifying *break*. I’m not sure; I think I’d be happier treating *break forth in* as a three-place phrasal verb of which *grass and flowers* is some sort of predicative (and, as you say, resultative) complement. Every ‘explosive’ term I can think of entertains this sort of complement:

   > The French at Rick's break into the *Marseillaise*.
   >   The night skies burst forth in fireworks.
   >   My boss exploded in rage.
   >   The arsenal blew up in a hailstorm of smoke and shrapnel.
   >   When she was 13 her face erupted in acne.

Both of these uses are distinct from that in *bored them stupid*; *stupid* is an unambiguous modifier on *them*, while *to go ...* is a clause of which *houses* is the subject, and *grass and flowers* is a noun phrase representing ... what? A feature added to the *topsoil* is the closest I can come. Certainly not a ‘modifier’ of *topsoil* in the ordinary sense, but just as certainly attributable to it, belonging to it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to say that *bore them all **stupid*** is just a (somewhat colloquial) manifestation of the same grammatical principle involved in *wipe the table **clean**?* And that OP's other two highlighted phrases aren't particularly related to either that or to each other?

Comment: I’ve found the adverbial use of ‘stupid’ meaning ‘extremely.’ http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stupid So it seems like having the same meaning with ‘bore stiff’ http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stiff

Comment: @StoneyB, I’m going to start reading his book from next month. It was not easy to decide to do so, for I’d like to just read my favorites. But without being helped by those kinds of books and these volunteer teachers like you, it is not easy to find out exact or deeper meanings. In fact. if professor Lawler and you weren’t here, I wouldn’t have any chance to read the book.

Comment: @Listenever It's **tough**. Very good writing, and full of meat, but a hard read. I got four chapters in and decided I had to go all the way back to the beginning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree about the *stupid* construction (which I think OP recognizes, too) and about the *to go* clause; but I the *grass and flowers* is syntactically related to the *stupid* construction.

Comment: @StoneyB, I’m not afraid, because there are ones who would melt the toughness away, in this page at least two including Mr. FumbleFingers. And as I’ve already said for deeper dialogue with storybooks, it’s inevitable for foreigner to read McCawley’s book. If it were just a grammar book, I wouldn’t dare. I think it would take at least over a year to get through once, this is why I hesitated.

Comment: @Listenever, StoneyB: I think the *grasses and flowers* usage is very different to *bore [someone] stupid*. One is a pair of ***nouns*** describing *[things]* produced by an action, the other is an *adjective* describing *a state of being* caused by an action. And you can't apply that adjectival usage in all superficially comparable contexts - for example, it wouldn't normally be considered valid to say *"The monsoon rained the land fertile"*. Only certain combinations of verb and adjective are idiomatically acceptable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I said they were very different; my initial point was that *resultative* does not describe the syntax. And take a step back - what's the deep structure? *Bored them stupid* includes *made them become stupid*, just as the rain *made the topsoil break forth*, while *break forth in flowers* includes *made flowers break forth*. Suppose Steinbeck had written *a rich winter of rain drenched the earth to fertility*, how does that line up against *she bored them to tears*? There's a lot of interesting stuff going on here.

Comment: If he'd written *a rich winter of rain drenched the earth to fertility* I suppose we'd have to accept it as a "poetic" usage, but we're not really concerned with "creative, but marginal" usage on a site where the primary purpose is to learn basic standard forms. And even if we allow *that* form, I think you'd have to roll your eyes at *a rich winter of rain drenched the earth fertile*. I honestly don't see that OP is going to learn any basic principles of "standard" grammar by classifying disparate usages as *resultative*.