# What is the role of 'level with' in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, secondary-predicates, locative

> "Give that here, Malfoy," said Harry quietly. Everyone stopped talking
>   to watch. 
>  Malfoy smiled nastily. 
>  "I think I'll leave it
>   somewhere for Longbottom to find - how about - up a tree?" 
>  "Give
>   it here!" Harry yelled, but Malfoy had leapt onto his broomstick and
>   taken off. He hadn't been lying, he could fly well. Hovering **level
>   with the topmost branches of an oak** he called, "Come and get it,
>   Potter!" 
>  Harry grabbed his broom.  
>  (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

The highlighted part looks like a [predicative complement](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/are-these-phrases-all-expressing-resultative-meaning). Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. *Level with* is an abbreviated form of *on a level with* here and acts as a compound preposition, like *next to*.

So what you have is a prepositional phrase acting as an adverb modifying the verbal adjective *hovering*. Hovering *where?* - level with the branches.

Comment: Isn't _level_ an adjective, in the same way it is in "She drew level with the police car."?

Comment: @kiamlaluno The distinction between adjectives of position and motion is often pretty arbitrary. In *a level playing field* level is unambiguously an adjective; but *the car drew level*? In any case, *level with* acts as compound preposition; consider the paradigm *above the branches*, *below the branches*, *level with the branches*.

Comment: I asked because the sentence I quoted is one of the examples for [level](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/level_2) used as adjective.

Comment: @kiamlaluno *Adverb* is a garbage category, but I have no hesitation in calling the bare use of level in *drew level* adverbial: *drew ahead*, *drew forward*, *drew back*, and the use with *with* in *drew level with* as a compound preposition.

Comment: I got what you meant; I was wondering why the dictionary would use that as example of using an adjective when the word follows a verb that is not a linking verb.

Comment: @kiamlaluno As I said, the distinction is arbitrary; you could take *draw* as copular here, as OP suggests in thinking of this as a predicative complement: Harry **is** level [with the branches], she **is** level [with the car]. Motion and position are inherently both adjectival and 'adverbial'; consider the dummy adverb *there* in *there is*. But I think the safest analysis is by way of the paradigms.

Answer (score 1):

"Hovering level with the topmost branches of an oak" means "Hovering **at the same level as**  the topmost branches of an oak."